# SOAPUI maven report not showing full log in the HTML report

Tags: maven, report, soapui, maven-surefire-plugin

I was able to generate a html report using maven with the "maven-surefire-report-plugin" but the HTML report is plain simple and does not have logs for each test.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Is it possible to have all the test steps under these test cases? The messages appears in the output log file, so something like this:

```
2016-09-30 22:43:50,822 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [SOAP Response] has status VALID
2016-09-30 22:43:50,822 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [Assert Success Message] has status VALID
2016-09-30 22:43:50,822 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [Valid HTTP Status Code 200] has status VALID
2016-09-30 22:43:50,822 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI
```